# If yes_list then... applescript

Tags: list, applescript, speech-recognition

Hi I am new to apple script but I am trying to make a stand alone application that upon request will open Apple Mail using yes and no lists. I am a newbie so any help would be appreciated. I have attached my code below.

```
set Unread_Count to unread count of inbox
if Unread_Count is 0 then
    say "Sir, it appears you have no new email's"
else if Unread_Count is 1 then
    say "You have 1 new email"
else
    say "You have " & (get Unread_Count) & " unread emails"
end if
end tell
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
set yes_list to {"yes", "yes open mail", "yes open mail server", "yes please"}
set no_list to {"That's all", "no"}

set answer to listen for yes_list & no_list with prompt "Would you like me to open your mail server? Or will that be all."
-- you have to hold the Listening key (by default ⎋) to record a reply
if answer is no_list then
    delay 0.2
    say "Very well sir."
end if

if answer is yes_list then
    tell application "Mail"
        reopen
        activate
end tell
end if
end tell
```

Unfortunately my actions are not working even though my commands are being recognized. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `contains` keyword:

```
tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    set l1 to {"yes", "maybe"}
    set l2 to {"no"}
    set answer to listen for l1 & l2 with prompt "prompt"
    l1 contains answer
end tell
```

If others test this, you have to enable speakable items from System Preferences first, and hold the listening key (by default escape) to record the answer.